# The model's performance is poor, and I want to confirm if this modeling approach is effective

Tags: lstm

I have a dataset with columns containing text and five different features (integers). I've embedded the text using GloVe and fed it into an LSTM along with the other features, but the performance of the model is not satisfactory.

```
def create_model(text_embedding_shape,text_embedding,features_shape,max_len):

    text_input = Input(shape=(max_len,),name='text')
    embeddings = Embedding(text_embedding_shape,100,weights = [text_embedding], trainable = False)(text_input)
    lstm_layer = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences = True))(embeddings)
    #lstm_normalized = BatchNormalization()(lstm_layer)
    attention_layer = Attention(use_scale=False)([lstm_layer, lstm_layer])
    dropout_layer = Dropout(0.3)(attention_layer)
    flatten_layer = Flatten()(dropout_layer)
    text_dense =(Dense(64, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001),activation='relu')(flatten_layer))

    features_input = Input(shape=(features_shape.shape[1], features_shape.shape[2]), name='feature')
    lstm_layer2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.3))(features_input)
    flatten_layer2 = Flatten()(lstm_layer2)
    feature_dense =(Dense(32, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), activation='relu')(flatten_layer2))
    concatenated_features = Concatenate()([text_dense, feature_dense])
    output_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(concatenated_features)

    model = Model(inputs=[text_input, features_input], outputs=output_layer)
    adam = Adam(learning_rate = 0.01)
    #adam = Adam(lr=1e-4)
    #sgd = SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()

    return model

    model = create_model(text_embedding.shape[0],text_embedding,X_train_features,max_len)
    history = model.fit([X_train_text, X_train_features], y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1,callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

I have tried adjusting multiple sets of different hyperparameters, but the best result I could achieve was an accuracy of 0.6 and an F1 score of 0.6.

The dataset consists of 5000 records, split into 8:1:1 for training, validation, and testing, respectively.

I'm aiming for an F1 score of 0.7. Could you please suggest any methods for improvement?